# Is `like` more expensive than `=` in New Relic?

Tags: newrelic, nrql

Given the following NRQL query:

`SELECT * FROM AppPerformance WHERE app LIKE '%stackoverflow%'`

Would this other query be cheaper in terms of performance and cost?

`SELECT * FROM AppPerformance WHERE app = 'stackoverflow'`

Comment: `app LIKE '%stackoverflow%'` is not equivalent to `app = 'stackoverflow'`, so you'd be comparing two entirely different things.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I know. I'm more concerned about the `=` and `LIKE` here. I know that I'll need to consider what results I'll get by changing the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the cost and performance of NRQL queries in New Relic depend on various factors, including the amount of data in your New Relic account and the query complexity. In general, using a more specific query is likely to be more efficient and cost-effective than using a wildcard pattern, especially if the wildcard pattern has the potential to match a large number of records.

In your case:

`SELECT * FROM AppPerformance WHERE app LIKE '%stackoverflow%'` uses a wildcard pattern to match any value of the `app` attribute that contains "stackoverflow" anywhere within it. This could potentially match a wide range of records, and the query may take longer to execute and consume more resources.

And `SELECT * FROM AppPerformance WHERE app = 'stackoverflow'` is more specific, as it only matches records where the `app` attribute is exactly equal to "stackoverflow." This is likely to be more efficient and cost-effective because it reduces the number of records that need to be scanned.

So, in terms of performance and cost, the second query likely to be cheaper and more efficient. It's always a good practice to use the most specific query that meets your requirements to optimize performance and reduce costs.

Comment: If you don't mind, would an extra condition make it more expensive or cheaper? For example, if I add `version = '1.0.0'`, is it more expensive because of the extra condition, or is it cheaper because it will potentially return fewer results?

Comment: See If the extra condition is highly selective(significantly reduces the number of records that match the query) it can be more efficient in cost and performance. Selective conditions reduce the amount of data that needs to be processed, making the query faster and less resource-intensive.
 \n 
And If the extra condition doesn't significantly reduce the number of matching records, it can potentially make the query more expensive because the database still has to evaluate the condition for a large number of records.

Comment: Would you have any New Relic references to back this? I'd like to share it where I work with more references.

Comment: Sure, See I've learned from working with various database query languages, but I can suggest these blog and doc. They are for SQL and PostgreSQL but relevant to our discussion. 

https://medium.com/@maanavshah/performance-optimization-for-like-queries-in-postgresql-514ba73d9244: This article talks about optimizing 'LIKE' queries in PostgreSQL, which can be applicable to query performance in general.

https://andrewrgoss.com/pdf/sql_query_optimization_techniques.pdf: This resource covers query optimization techniques that can be broadly applied.